# Optimising a Mech pilot

Tags: optimization, mutants-and-masterminds, mecha

We are playing a *Mutants and Masterminds* campaign in the [Eureka Seven universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_Seven) and using [R505 Sumner model LFOs](http://www.mahq.net/mecha/eureka7/newvision/r505-sumner.htm). The GM has already statted out the mecha in the system. We get to customize it a little and outfit our pilots with equipment, skills, and feats. There are no superhumans in the setting.

**How can I optimise a Pilot for mecha combat and occasional non-mech ground combat?**

All I'm looking for really is suggestions on the human pilot aspect. I'm looking for feats that (for example) make the PC a better pilot, skills besides Pilot that might help combat, or feats that make the mecha better. I am not allowed any Super abilities.

My GM is setting the Power Level at "approximately 2" and giving us 22 PP. Quoting my GM:

> The power level is approximately 2. 
>   power-level 1 or 2 not sure yet all 
>   that u will NEED is 40 equipment points 
>   a feat and skills i think one and a half 
>   so about 22 PP i think

Also not allowed to have above Human stats. because we are all human and either military or Ex Military.

Comment: Honestly i think he could give us more points to work with as we need mechs but we also need skills and saves.

Comment: Just a comment. At PL2, you wont be able to blast through wood.

Answer (score 5):

PL2 is a real challenge, because the system assumes you are around PL10 and I've only seen one game below PL5.

You need to maximise each point. My personal advice is buying *Device, hard to lose* to make yourself a suit. Ask your GM if you can have a suit like the following:

> #### Flightsuit (Device 3) - Cost 12 PP
>
> Hard to lose
>
> **Augmented Reality Visor**: (Super senses) Radio, Time sense, Tracking, Distance sense, Direction sense. Datalink 2 (control computer 20 feet away from you)
>
> **Safety Systems**: Protection 2, Immunity 4 (Suffocation, Gravity)

This would be part of your character at all times which is really good and cheap. You've spent only 12 PP and you have something fun already!

Next take an equipment feat to get some weapons appropriate to your character and setting (which I'm not familiar with). For other feats I recommend **Attack Focus (Ranged)**, **Dodge Focus**, and **Improved Aim**, all  with two ranks. The **Favorite Environment (Space)** feat will be a must for space combat.

That's not a full character build but general advice. PL2 is really hard to build.

Comment: @Novian A flight suit doesn't let you *fly*, it's what a pilot wears. Notice that "fly" isn't a power mentioned anywhere in this answer.

Comment: comment erased. although I dont think they had specific suits for mecha piloting either. i think the "dress code" was street clothes. its a very limiting setting. Now if we did a Another Centuries Episode style campaign.....

Comment: @Novian In which case a custom flight suit would be an unusual advantage, perfect for spending points on…